# LibGDX Label scaling on Stage

Tags: libgdx

I'm trying to show a label on the Stage with virtual 16:9 size:

```
public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter {

    private Stage stage;

    @Override
    public void create () {
        stage = new Stage(new FillViewport(16, 9));
        Label label = new Label("What's wrong with labels?",
                new Label.LabelStyle(new BitmapFont(), Color.WHITE));
        label.setBounds(0, 0, 16, 9);
        stage.addActor(label);
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        stage.act();
        stage.draw();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose () {
        stage.dispose();
    }
}
```

The font looks huge and can't fit screen bounds:

[image]

Then I try to set font scale and word wrapping:

```
    stage = new Stage(new FillViewport(16, 9));
    Label label = new Label("What's wrong with labels?",
            new Label.LabelStyle(new BitmapFont(), Color.WHITE));
    label.setBounds(0, 0, 16, 9);
    label.setFontScale(0.1f);
    label.setWrap(true);
    stage.addActor(label);
```

And getting messed completely:

[image]

Tried settings viewport size in pixels, like 1080:1920. In this case label is shown small, as expected. But I'd like to have my world size (16:9) work with labels. Can you suggest me how to scale down the font properly?

Comment: scaling is never worthy, you should create resources according to your viewport. I prefer to work with 480:800 in portrait mode.

Comment: @AbhishekAryan yep, seems I need stage with near-resolution dimensions to display fonts. That's sad, seems textures and fonts are scaled differently...